# EXTJS Remote Combobox

Tags: combobox, extjs4, remote-server

I have a combo box with a store getting data from a server via remote. My problem is that my pagination does not work. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  Ext.define('EmployeeModel', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
        {name:'id', type:'int'},
        {name:'fullname', type:'string'}
     ]
  });

  // remote store
  var employeeStore= new Ext.data.Store(
  {
     model: 'EmployeeModel',
     pageSize: 10, 
     proxy: {
        url: '/schedule/home/EmployeeList',
        params: {
           'active_id': params
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        autoLoad: true,
        reader: 
        {
           root: 'data',
           totalProperty: 'total',
           id: 'id',
           type: 'json'
        },
        simpleSortMode: true 
     }
  });



  this.employeeBox = new Ext.form.ComboBox(
  {
     store: employeeStore,
     displayField: 'fullname',
     valueField: 'id',
     typeAhead: false,
     loadingText: 'Searching...',
     triggerAction: 'all',
     hiddenName: 'employee',
     name: 'Employee Name',
     fieldLabel: 'Employee',
     selectOnFocus: true,
     allowBlank: false,
     anchor: '98%',
     width: 370,
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     pageSize: true,
     minListWidth: 220,
     minChars: 2,
     labelWidth: this.labelWidth,
     resizable: false 
  });
```

I dont know what is lacking but as far as i have searched through the internet I copied and tested everything, still it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have remote store, paging also should be remote. `pageSize` is only parameter which is send to server, where you should handle paging. Beside `pageSize` you will also see parameters like `start` and `limit`.

You can see example here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/forum-search.html
Check out requests in firebug or something similiar, you will see url like this: `http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-remote.php?_dc=1354611968514&query=form&page=2&start=10&limit=10&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback3`

If you want to have paging on client side, you can create local store and preload data via custom AJAX request.

Comment: as what i observed it loaded the result  but not paginated. In my URL stated above it comes from a php file that return a "json_encode"-ed array from a query. Which my query is getting the characters every key press. Is there something that i should in my query? BTW I am using symfony 1.4

Comment: `http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-remote.php` is definitely paginated - see [this link](http://www.picamatic.com/view/8854690_Untitled/) if you don't believe :) I don't know symphony, so I won't tell you how to do it. Usually remote paging is made in SQL query.